# Cannot access class variable outside class - kivy

Tags: kivy

Anytime i try to run my app i get error.

Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

See code snippet below

```
class Login(Screen):

    email_obj = ObjectProperty()
    password_obj = ObjectProperty()
    conn = lite.connect("database/nairamanager.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    def init(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    # Display an alert on login validation
    def login_alert(self):
        p = LoginAlert()
        p.open()

    # Get user from database
    def login_nm_user(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_tb WHERE email_db = ? AND password_db = ?;", (self.email_obj.text, self.password_obj.text))
        if self.cursor.fetchall():
            self.manager.current = "news_feed_screen"
        else:
            return self.login_alert()
            self.conn.commit()
            # self.conn.close

    # Get user email
    def get_user_email(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user_tb WHERE email_db = ?;", (self.email_obj.text))
        self.user_email = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
        self.conn.commit()
        print(self.user_email)


login = Login()
login.get_user_email()
print(login.user_email)
```

.kv code
Below is the Login class in the kivy lang file

```
<Login>:

email_obj: email_text
password_obj: password_text


GridLayout:
    size: root.size
    rows: 2
    rows_minimum: {0:0,1:root.height*.7}
    spacing: 50
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        row_default_minimum: True
        rows_minimum: {0:root.height*.1,1:root.height*.01}
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            BackButton:
                text: "L"
                size_hint: (.1,1)
                halign: "center"
                markup: True
                on_press:
                    root.manager.current = "login_signup_screen"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            TopLabel:
                text: "[b]Lets get you logged in...[/b]"
                size_hint: (.9,1)
        BorderLabel:

    # Login form
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 20
        UniTextInput:
            id: email_text
            hint_text: "Email"
            size_hint: (.6,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        UniTextInput:
            id: password_text
            hint_text: "Password"
            password: True
            size_hint: (.6,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
        GreenButton
            id: main_login_button
            text: "Login"
            size_hint: (.6,1)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5}
            on_press:
                root.login_nm_user()
                root.get_user_email()

        # Fake widget for spacing
        Widget:
        Widget:
        Widget:
```

Please, how do i fix this?

Comment: Consider editing the question and adding the full stacktrace

Comment: Also, as far as we see, `email_obj` is just an `ObjectProperty()`. Where do you get the attribute `text` from?

Comment: from the .kv file, there is a TextInput Widget defined with an id(email_text) and email_obj is set to email_text. Thus, email_obj.text gets the data entered by the user. @EL3PHANTEN

Answer (score 0):

To share a variable to all screens, you can make it an attribute of the screenmanager.
Like this:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    user_email = StringProperty()

class Login(Screen):

    def login(self, user, pw):
        # login
        # if pass
        self.manager.user_email = user
        self.manager.current = "screen2"


root = Builder.load_string('''

MyScreenManager:

    Login:
        name: "login"
        id: login
        BoxLayout:

            orientation: 'vertical'

            TextInput:
                id: email_input
            TextInput:
                id: password_input
            Button:
                text: "Login"
                on_release: login.login(email_input.text, password_input.text)


    Screen:
        name: "screen2"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"    
            Label:
                text: "Wellcome {}!".format(root.user_email)
            Button:
                text: "Go to screen 3" 
                on_release: root.current = "screen3"

    Screen:
        name: "screen3"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"    
            Label:
                text: "Wellcome {}!".format(root.user_email)
            Button:
                text: "Go back to screen 2" 
                on_release: root.current = "screen2"

''')

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
       return root

MyApp().run()
```

That said, I see you define a `init` method. If you really want to overite the `__init__`, remember the underscores.
In this particular example, you dont really do anything in the init. `super().__init__()` gets executed anyways when you create a new `Screen`

Comment: You are right, that was a typo but that is not the problem. Corrected the OQ, thanks. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @WilsonReuben ok. Updated my answer

Comment: My identation is right, i don't know why SO does that or maybe it is just me. What i am trying to achieve is this, i am trying to store a database column in a python variable so i can call it in my other screens from the get_user_email method in the Login class-something like sessions-if you know the best way to do this please share. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: How can i make you understand? When the user logs in, a session is saved telling the app that this is the current user logged in and i want that to reflect on all screens showing the users email. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @WilsonReuben ah affirmative. Updated

Comment: Aha! Let me give that a try. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: I celebrate you. It works like charm! Thank you very much, so happy. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @WilsonReuben finally :D you are wellcome

Comment: @WilsonReuben, altho this is not really a session. You would have to store a session on the phone or computer if you want the user still to be logged in even if he really closes the app.

Comment: How do i accomplish that? @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @WilsonReuben then you can write to a database. If you want a timeout, you can check when the user was on last time. There are probably other ways.

Comment: I am already using a database but don't know what you are talking about. If you please share some light. @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: @WilsonReuben you can save the time a user logged in. And in your app, you check if that time is within 10 minutes or something, if so, log the user in automatically. And maybe have a "stay logged in" checkbox. So in your database you save which user is loged in.

Comment: @WilsonReuben also we should move this to chat. It has nothing to do with the question about "accessing variable outside class"

Comment: I can't move to chat because i have only 6 reputations. If you can, please move to chat, thanks.

Comment: @WilsonReuben http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139861/python-database

Comment: Says i must have 20 reputation to chat! Can we chat through mail or telegram? @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: Which is better so i can join? @EL3PHANTEN

Comment: Just did that @EL3PHANTEN